# Can't run Flutter app in emulator or real device

Tags: android, flutter

I wanted to check out what's it like to develop using Flutter. I have followed https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started tutorial and got everything set up, but I am stuck on an error, which is given both when trying to run an app on an emulator or on my OnePlus 5T

I have restarted adb, put my phone on File Transfer mode, checked flutter doctor - no errors.

Here is the error log (it's same for both emulator and my phone)

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
--------- beginning of main
06-08 12:54:00.721 I/GnssLocationProvider( 1843): WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@f147ecd)
Unhandled exception:
Exit code -1073740940 from: E:/ProgramData/Android_Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:360:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:289:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:513:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:688:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:318:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:361:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:253:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:389:23)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:449:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:819:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:447:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:383:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:301:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:559:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:294:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

flutter doctor -v log:

```
E:\src\flutter>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.145], locale lv-LV)
• Flutter version 1.5.4-hotfix.2 at E:\src\flutter
• Framework revision 7a4c33425d (6 weeks ago), 2019-04-29 11:05:24 -0700
• Engine revision 52c7a1e849
• Dart version 2.3.0 (build 2.3.0-dev.0.5 a1668566e5)

-Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at E:\ProgramData\Android_Sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• ANDROID_HOME = E:\ProgramData\Android_Sdk
• Java binary at: E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
• Android Studio at E:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 36.0.1
• Dart plugin version 183.6270
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
• ONEPLUS A5010 • 44e0967d • android-arm • Android null (API null)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: what's the output of `flutter doctor -v`?

Comment: @MichaelYuwono I added the output on my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > > Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

This problem is with the new update of Android Studio (29)

There is a temporary fix for now (if you're using Windows)!

**1.** Close Android Studio

**2.** Open CMD and write:  `taskkill /f /im adb.exe`

**3.** Download this file: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

**4.** Go to

> C:\Users[your-username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

and replace the "platform-tools" folder with the new one that you just downloaded.

ps: (a) don't forget to keep the backup (b) the AppData is a hidden folder